# Electron app can't seek buffer in production

Tags: html5-video, electron

I am using Electron to create a desktop application that plays a video loading locally in the same directory as the HTML.

When using the app in development I am able to seek the buffer with success (I change the time of the video and it searches for other bytes)

Initially it gets the data of the video from byte 0:

```
Request URL:file:///path_to_electron/electron-boilerplate/build/HQ.mp4
Range:bytes=0-
```

And when I change the time it seeks for the new piece of the video in another request if it is not in the buffer:

```
Request URL:file:///path_to_electron/electron-boilerplate/build/HQ.mp4
Range:bytes=89784320-
```

If I run it in production environment I get this initially:

```
Request URL:file:///Applications/app_name/Contents/Resources/app.asar/HQ.mp4
Range:bytes=0-
```

But if I try to go to a time that I don't have in the buffer it crashes with video error 3 (MEDIA_ERR_DECODE - error occurred when decoding)

```
Request URL:file:///Applications/app_name/Contents/Resources/app.asar/HQ.mp4
Range:bytes=89784320-    
Error code:  3
```

I don't get the difference from running it for development or in production that could generate this error

Answer (score 0):

Whenyou run your production script, it generates an `asar` package with all your app in it.

> An `asar` archive is a simple tar-like format that concatenates files into a single file. Electron can read arbitrary files from it without unpacking the whole file.

However this comes with some limitations and one of these is that the archives in the `asar` are `read-only` so maybe the library is trying to modify the video or another file and there it throws the error.

[Application Packaging (asar info)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md)